# How to implement Ignore/Retry/Cancel pattern for an action?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a two layered Windows-Forms application developed by C#.NET 4.0 . In this APP i read a file content and create a list of entities in Data-Access-Layer, and return it to GUI-Layer to show in a grid view. In my current logic, if one of the lines in the file has corrupted or bad-formatted (that i can't create an entity from it) or any other exceptions, i throw an exception and abort the process. Now, how can i implement an Ignore/Retry/Cancel pattern? I mean what is the best way to show an Ignore/Retry/Cancel dialog box and do whatever user wants (eg. ignore the current line and goto next line, cancel the process, or retry the current failed line read) ? is there any pattern for it?

Answer (score 11):

I adopt the following pattern when offering such options:

```
DialogResult result = DialogResult.Retry;
while (result == DialogResult.Retry) {
    try {
        DoProcess();
        break;
    }
    catch {
        result = MessageBox.Show(errorMessage, caption, MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore);
        if (result == DialogResult.Abort) throw;
    }
}
```

If the user selects Retry, the loop will run again. If the user clicks Abort, the exception will be thrown (to be caught further up the chain and thus abort the rest of the operation). Ignore will cause the loop to exit without throwing an exception. I can't think of a more concise way of doing this.

Comment: thanks. but my problem is that my action does a complete process (like read the entire lines in the file) and i can't tell it ignore one line. i think it's not your problem and i must change the design of my codes. thanks again.

Comment: It sounds like you need to break your process down somewhat, if you want to be able to selectively skip over steps which might fail. Maybe consider an enumerator pattern, where the GUI front-end repeatedly calls a method on the back-end until it returns false to indicate that no more processing remains to be done?

Comment: thanks, excellent answer, it's a shame that other users can accept as answer, because this user has 31% of accepted rate. +1